# WebGL model frame and world frame relational

Tags: webgl, coordinates

I had trouble with understand the relationship between model frame and world frame.
If
P is the perspective projection matrix (transform from view frame to clip coordinates)
V is the view matrix (transform from world to view frame)
M is the model matrix (transform from model to world frame, may include non-uniform scale)
s_w is a light source location point (in the world frame)
p_m is a point on the model surface (in the model frame)
n_m is the unit surface normal vector at  (in the model frame)

What are the best answer for following?

a. The final projected location of p_m in clip coordinates

b. The vector in the view frame from the transformed p_m toward the transformed light source

c. The vector in the view frame from the transformed p_m towards the center of projection

d. The normal vector n_m in view coordinates (before normalization)

For a matrix A, the transpose is indicated by A^T, and the inverse by A^-1.

Choose from one of them below:
1. V (M^-1)^T n_m
2. (0,0,0,1) - (V M p_m) 
3. s_w - (M p_m) 
4. V M n_m 
5. P M V p_m 
6. V M^-1 n_m 
7. (V s_w) - (V M p_m) 
8. (0,0,0,1) - p_m 
9. s_w - p_m 
10. (P V s_w) - (P V M p_m) 
11. V M^T n_m 
12. V - p_m 
13. p_m P V M 
14. M V P p_m 
15. P V M p_m 
16. (0,0,0,0) - (V M p_m)

Answer (score 0):

a = 15

b = 7

c = 2

d = 1

I think.

You might find [this article](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-lighting-point.html) useful

Comment: Thanks for the answering and article. I will take look